# Subsetting a dataset, adding column and rows in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset that has 5 columns and 50 rows. I want to divide it into two parts, one with 35 rows and 15 in the other randomly. Then i would like to add another column to this dataset which contains value TRUE/FALSE. TRUE if the row belongs to the 35 randomly selected rows and FALSE if it belongs to the 15. How do i achieve it in R...
All help is greatly appreciated..
Thanks

Comment: No effort at all. Just give me teh codez

Answer (score 2):

We create a `vector` of 'TRUE/FALSE' elements using `rep` by specifying the `times` to replicate the 'TRUE/FALSE' values, `sample` it, and create a new column ('ind') by assigning the output.  Then, `split` the dataset into a `list` of 2 `data.frame`s by 'ind' column.

```
df1$ind <- sample(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), times = c(35, 15)))
split(df1, df1$ind)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(9, 50*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```